# How to make frequency matrix from several other matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, frequency

I have 30 matrices (1446x1124) containing values going from 0 to 99. 
I would like to have an output matrix, having the same size and containing in each cell the frequency of ouccrence (between 0 and 1) of one element of this matrix (for example 2) over the 30 input matrices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your matrices are stored properly. If they are all the same size I would recommend a 3 dimensional matrix. Then it should look something like this:

```
M = round(rand(30,1446,1124));
```

Now I am not sure what shape you want the output to have, but suppose you want to know the fraction of 2s it is quite simple:

```
mean(M(:)==2)
```